# Updating SQL Database With Checkbox Values

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I know this has been answered a few times, but I just can't seem to get mine working!

I have 8 weeks in my database (set up as columns) and I display the value of these with php as follows

```
<form method="post" id="updating" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">

        <?php
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($results as $v) {
            while($count<9){
                $week = Week.$count;
                $checkvalue = $v -> $week;
                ?>
                Week<?echo $count;?> <input type="checkbox" id="Week<?php echo$count;?>" name="week[]" value="<?php echo $checkvalue;?>" <?php if($checkvalue==1){?>
                checked="checked"
                <?php } ?>
                />
                <?php   
                $count++; 
            }
        }
        ?>
        <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
    </form>
```

I know it's probably not as graceful as it should be, but it does output the correct HTML for me and displays the information as it's presented in the database.

```
<form method="post" id="updating" action="">

        Week1 <input type="checkbox" id="Week1" name="week[]" value="1"     checked="checked"
        />
    Week2 <input type="checkbox" id="Week2" name="week[]" value="0"     />
    Week3 <input type="checkbox" id="Week3" name="week[]" value="1"     checked="checked"
        />
    Week4 <input type="checkbox" id="Week4" name="week[]" value="1"     checked="checked"
        />
    Week5 <input type="checkbox" id="Week5" name="week[]" value="0"     />
    Week6 <input type="checkbox" id="Week6" name="week[]" value="1"     checked="checked"
        />
    Week7 <input type="checkbox" id="Week7" name="week[]" value="1"     checked="checked"
        />
    Week8 <input type="checkbox" id="Week8" name="week[]" value="1"     checked="checked"
        />
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</form>
```

The problem I'm having is when I tick or untick those checkboxes, the updated values don't appear to be captured, and hence the database isn't being updated properly. Here's where the self post request is handled.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $count = 1;
    if(isset($_POST['week']) && !empty($_POST['week']))   
    foreach($_POST['week'] as $w){ echo $w; //prints 1 all the time
$week = Week.$count;
echo $week;//prints out weeks I want to update correctly (database headings)
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Fields to update.
$fields = array(
    $week.'=' . $db->quote( $w ));

// Conditions for which records should be updated.
$conditions = array(
    'UserID='. (int) $user_id);

$query->update($db->quoteName('tools_engage'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);

try {
    $result = $db->query(); // Use $db->execute() for Joomla 3.0.
    echo ("Values saved and updated </br>");
    $count++;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Catch the error.
}
}
}?>
```

I'm doing this in Joomla, hence the weird database update syntax, but it does work and I've used them elsewhere in this program so I know they're not the problem

As I commented in the code, the array week[] just seems to contain the value 1 for everything, no matter what boxes I check or uncheck. Which then results in every value in the database being updated to 1/true which obviously isn't right.

I have a suspicion the problem lies in my HTML output for the update form, but can't seem to crack it, any help is much appreciated!

**Update:**
Ok so going on nvuono's suggestion I have updated my form to be like this

```
<?php
$count = 1;
foreach ($results as $v) {
while($count<9){
    $week = Week.$count;
    $checkvalue = $v -> $week;
    ?>
    Week<?echo $count;?> <input type="checkbox" id="Week<?php echo$count;?>" name="week[<?php echo $count;?>]" value="1" <?php if($checkvalue==1){?>
    checked="checked"
    <?php } ?>
    />
<?php   
$count++; 
}
}
?>
```

So now each name has an index in the array does it not? If that is the case, should my

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
```

section not now be printing out all the values in the array in the order they've been entered?

ie. My logic would be that it prints out 1,0,0,1,0,0,0 (box 1 and 4 checked) or what ever boxes are checked. But instead it just prints out 1,1 so I've no way of knowing what index they are, and subsequently what week I should be updating

Comment: I linked this down below but it might help you, too:  [checkboxes, php, and post](http://www.wastedpotential.com/html-multi-checkbox-set-the-correct-way-to-group-checkboxes/).  Make sure the correct info is being sent (so before the post) and make sure `$_Post['week']` gets the same data...

Comment: thanks for that, and that all makes sense to me, but I have updated the question with the specific problem I'm having, hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some really hacky way of doing the update.  You need to beware of SQL Injection and other bad things when using `post`... make sure you always validate and sanitize your data.  The "hacky" way works because we're working with integer values and those are easily cleaned.

Screenshot:

[image]

This is my table... I called it so for stackoverflow...

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 | week5 | week6 | week7 | week8 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|  2 | 1     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|  3 | 1     |       | 1     |       |       |       |       |       |
|  4 | 1     |       | 1     |       | 1     |       |       |       |
|  5 | 1     |       | 1     |       | 1     |       | 1     |       |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

This is my PHP file.... (stick it in an empty PHP document to run, it's self contained besides changing the db connection and query)

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "test"); 

if (!empty($_POST)) {
   print "<pre>POST VARS: \n".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";

   foreach($_POST as $i => $data) 
   { 
      if (substr($i,0,3)=='row' && is_numeric(substr($i,3)))
      {
         $row_id = substr($i,3);  
         $data = array_flip($data); 
         $values = array(); 

         for ($x=1; $x<9; $x++) {
            $values[] = "week$x = ". ((isset($data[$x])) ? '1' : '0');  
         }   

         $stmt = "\nupdate so ".
                 "\n  set ".implode(", \n      ",$values).
                 "\n  where id = $row_id; \n"; 

         $update = $mysqli->query($stmt); 
         if ($update) { print "Row $row_id updated successfully.<br/>"; } 
      }
      print "<br/>"; 
   }
}
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from so"); 

$mysqli->close();
?>

<form method="post" id="updating" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>"> 
   <?php
   while($row = $result->fetch_object())
   {

      $count = 1;

      print "<div style='border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;'>\n";
      print "Row ".$row->id."<br/>\n"; 
      while($count < 9) 
      {
         $week = "week$count";

         $checkvalue = $row->{$week};
         ?>
         Week<?php echo $count ?> <input type="checkbox" id="Week<?php echo$count;?>" name="row<?php echo $row->id 
         ?>[]" value="<?php echo $count;?>" <?php if($checkvalue==1){
         ?>  checked="checked" <?php } ?> />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <?php   
         $count++; 
      }
      print "</div><br/><br/>\n\n\n"; 
   }
   ?>
        <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
    </form>
```

This is the `$_POST` after submit:

```
POST VARS: 
Array
(
    [row2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [row3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [row4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
        )

    [row5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 7
        )

    [update] => Update
)
```

My "view source" of the form:

```
<form method="post" id="updating" action=""> 
   <div style='border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;'>
Row 1<br/>
         Week1 <input type="checkbox" id="Week1" name="row1[]" value="1"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week2 <input type="checkbox" id="Week2" name="row1[]" value="2"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week3 <input type="checkbox" id="Week3" name="row1[]" value="3"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week4 <input type="checkbox" id="Week4" name="row1[]" value="4"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week5 <input type="checkbox" id="Week5" name="row1[]" value="5"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week6 <input type="checkbox" id="Week6" name="row1[]" value="6"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week7 <input type="checkbox" id="Week7" name="row1[]" value="7"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week8 <input type="checkbox" id="Week8" name="row1[]" value="8"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </div><br/><br/>


<div style='border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;'>
Row 2<br/>
         Week1 <input type="checkbox" id="Week1" name="row2[]" value="1"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week2 <input type="checkbox" id="Week2" name="row2[]" value="2"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week3 <input type="checkbox" id="Week3" name="row2[]" value="3"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week4 <input type="checkbox" id="Week4" name="row2[]" value="4"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week5 <input type="checkbox" id="Week5" name="row2[]" value="5"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week6 <input type="checkbox" id="Week6" name="row2[]" value="6"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week7 <input type="checkbox" id="Week7" name="row2[]" value="7"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week8 <input type="checkbox" id="Week8" name="row2[]" value="8"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </div><br/><br/>


<div style='border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;'>
Row 3<br/>
         Week1 <input type="checkbox" id="Week1" name="row3[]" value="1"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week2 <input type="checkbox" id="Week2" name="row3[]" value="2"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week3 <input type="checkbox" id="Week3" name="row3[]" value="3"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week4 <input type="checkbox" id="Week4" name="row3[]" value="4"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week5 <input type="checkbox" id="Week5" name="row3[]" value="5"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week6 <input type="checkbox" id="Week6" name="row3[]" value="6"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week7 <input type="checkbox" id="Week7" name="row3[]" value="7"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week8 <input type="checkbox" id="Week8" name="row3[]" value="8"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </div><br/><br/>


<div style='border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;'>
Row 4<br/>
         Week1 <input type="checkbox" id="Week1" name="row4[]" value="1"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week2 <input type="checkbox" id="Week2" name="row4[]" value="2"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week3 <input type="checkbox" id="Week3" name="row4[]" value="3"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week4 <input type="checkbox" id="Week4" name="row4[]" value="4"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week5 <input type="checkbox" id="Week5" name="row4[]" value="5"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week6 <input type="checkbox" id="Week6" name="row4[]" value="6"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week7 <input type="checkbox" id="Week7" name="row4[]" value="7"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week8 <input type="checkbox" id="Week8" name="row4[]" value="8"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </div><br/><br/>


<div style='border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;'>
Row 5<br/>
         Week1 <input type="checkbox" id="Week1" name="row5[]" value="1"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week2 <input type="checkbox" id="Week2" name="row5[]" value="2"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week3 <input type="checkbox" id="Week3" name="row5[]" value="3"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week4 <input type="checkbox" id="Week4" name="row5[]" value="4"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week5 <input type="checkbox" id="Week5" name="row5[]" value="5"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week6 <input type="checkbox" id="Week6" name="row5[]" value="6"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week7 <input type="checkbox" id="Week7" name="row5[]" value="7"   checked="checked"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Week8 <input type="checkbox" id="Week8" name="row5[]" value="8"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </div><br/><br/>


        <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
    </form>
```

**edit**
I came back to this answer to reference something and I just realized I was re-using `ID` values for the checkboxes.  It wasn't a problem in this situation but it is always bad practice.  Each checkbox should have an ID that is unique on the page.  So.... it should really be `id="row1week1"`, `id="row1week2"`... `id="row8week1"`... `id="row8week8"`.

Comment: You sir, have just ended a long headache for me! Thank you so much! You actually had more than I needed (I only have 1 row of checkfields to update) but I was able to piece together and figure out the rest. Joomla functions handle all the code cleansing when updating the database too. I'm new to php so I wasn't fully aware of what I could do, this helped me a great deal! Thanks again