# Submit of selected on checkbox items?

Tags: php, html

I *print* this form in a web page with php:

```
<?php
    include("connectDB.php");
    $mySQL=new MySQL();
    $queryResult=$mySQL->query("SELECT nombre, precio, id_producto FROM productos");
    echo "<form action= 'checkout.php'> method=''POST'";
    while($datos=$mySQL->fetch_array($queryResult))
    {   
        $n = 1;
        $nombre=$datos['nombre'];
        $id_producto=$datos['id_producto'];
        $precio=$datos['precio'];

        echo "<h1>$nombre</h1>";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$id_producto\" value=\"$nombre\"> Cantidad: <input type=\"number\" name=\"points\" min=\"1\" max=\"20\" step=\"1\" value=\"1\"><br>";
        echo "<h3>  Precio: $precio<br>";

    }

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" value=\"Comprar\">";
    echo "</form>";
?>
```

So it displays a list (which is a form within) of items which can be selected or checked, on submit, I want to do the `$_POST['']` of only the checked items, how could I solve this?

Comment: I answered someone's post a while ago about how checkboxes work with forms, submitting and updating the DB.  [Maybe it could help you?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18641541/623952).  Checkboxes work off of their `name` and will be passed to post as an array of the **values** checked off... I think your html might have some errors in it, too.. `echo "<form action= 'checkout.php'> method=''POST'";` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When such checkboxes are printed, only those values which were checked are submitted.

If i understood you correctly you wanted to retrieve those that got posted, which you can follow with this simple method

```
    foreach($_POST as $post_key => $post_value){

        //Check that the particular input is int and numeric, since i believe the name is the id
        if(is_numeric($post_key) && is_int($post_key){
         //Here goes your code, $post_key is the id and $post_value is the $nombre
         //Although i admit that i have no idea what nombre is since it is in another language. Forgive me if id_producto is not numeric and unique.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nombre means **name** :)

Comment: Nice. If you find the answer helpful, don't forget to accept it by clicking the green arrow to the right :)