# Updating multiple rows in mysql with checkboxes?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using checkbox buttons for updating occupation of day in month in my calendar.

If I check just one checkbox it updates it, but if I check multiple checkboxes it doesn't update any row.

Here is my code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM koledar");
while ($vsidnevi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $dnevi = [$vsidnevi['dan']];
    foreach ($dnevi as $dan) {
        if ($vsidnevi['zasedenost']==0) {
            echo '<label class="btn btn-primary">';
            echo '<input type="checkbox"  name="miha" value="' . $dan . '" data-toggle="button">' . $dan;
            echo '</label>';
        } elseif ($vsidnevi['zasedenost']==1) {
            echo '<label class="btn btn-primary active disabled">';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="miha" value="' . $dan . '" data-toggle="button">' . $dan;
            echo '</label>';
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
if (isset($_GET['dodaj']) && $_GET['dodaj']=="true") {
    if(isset($_POST['miha'])) { 
        $daen = $_POST['miha'];
        $dodaj = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE koledar SET zasedenost=1 WHERE dan=" . $daen . "");
    } 
}
```

Comment: [Updating SQL Database With Checkbox Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623591/updating-sql-database-with-checkbox-values/18641541#18641541)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be passing your literal values to MySQL as parameters to a prepared statement (in order to defeat SQL injection attacks).

When multiple values are submitted, `$_POST['miha']` will be an array over which you must loop:

```
if (isset($_GET['dodaj']) && $_GET['dodaj']=="true") {
    if(isset($_POST['miha'])) { 
        $dodaj = mysqli_prepare($con, '
            UPDATE koledar
            SET    zasedenost=1
            WHERE  dan=?
        ');
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dodaj, 's', $daen);
        foreach ($_POST['miha'] as $daen) {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($dodaj);
        }
    } 
}
```

Or else use `IN ()`:

```
if (isset($_GET['dodaj']) && $_GET['dodaj']=="true") {
    if(isset($_POST['miha'])) {
        $inq = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['miha']), '?'));
        $dodaj = mysqli_prepare($con, "
            UPDATE koledar
            SET    zasedenost=1
            WHERE  dan IN ($inq)
        ");

        call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(
            array(
                $dodaj,
                str_repeat('s', count($_POST['miha']))
            ),
            $_POST['miha']
        ));
        mysqli_stmt_execute($dodaj);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @user2925624: Would you care to be more explicit?